# Is there a way of getting the current page's title on a SharePoint Page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am using SharePoint 2013 on-prem.  I am attempting to use the Title attribute (column) from Site Pages (list) as the pageTitle for the corresponding page.  I know that I could hard-code going through the Site Pages list for the title, but I would like to use some property on the page or a direct call to get the page's title and replace the pageTitle tag.

Comment: `document.title` ?

Comment: That actually provides the site and the name, not the title field of the page.  So on my site page called Project on my Development site with a title of Project Summary I would get Development - Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to display the Site Pages Title column in the corresponding page, then you can use Rest API to get it and display in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
                   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$filter=Id eq '"+_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId+"' ",
                   method: "GET",
                   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                   success: function (data) {
                            $("#PageTitle").html(data.d.results[0].Title);

                  },
                  error: function (data) {
                      alert("Error: "+ data);
                 }
          });
</script>
<div id="PageTitle"></div>
```

[image]

This is the return Json format for the page item:
[image]

Comment: You are correct, this does provide it, but then I need to overwrite what is displayed as the page name at the top of the page by using the command: document.getElementById('pageTitle').innerHTML=pageTitle;  I'm not an expert so I getting that div into a variable to be used by js is where I would then have problems.

Comment: $("#PageTitle").html(data.d.results[0].Title);
this line will make Page Title display in "PageTitle" div, no need to write document.getElementById('PageTitle') again...

Comment: Found the problem.  it's lower case #pageTitle.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

using the SharePoint context you could use `SPContext.Current.Item["Title"]` for documents or `SPContext.Current.List.Title` for lists.

Comment: //Not able to get this to work (using either option).
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myFunction,"sp.js");

function myFunction(){
   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var pagedisplay = clientContext.Current.Item["Title"];
}
</script>